# Django forms is not valid

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

my page html :

```
resrver salle !

<form>

    {%  csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="reserver">

        </form>
```

views .py :

```
def reserversalle(request , id):

form= ReserverSalle(request.POST or None)
print(form)
if form.is_valid():
    print("gooddd")
context= { 
        'form' : form ,
    }
return render(request,'registration/reserversalle.html', context)
```

forms.py :

```
   class ReserverSalle(forms.Form):
    nomsalle = forms.CharField(required=True , widget=forms.TextInput)
    motifresa = forms.CharField(required=True , widget=forms.TextInput)
    datedebut = forms.DateField( initial="2019-06-21", 
    widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=YEARS))
    heuredebut = forms.TimeField( initial='00:00:00')
    heurefin = forms.TimeField( initial='00:00:00')
```

hello  i try to submit my form but my form is not valid please i need some help

Comment: Your form does not specify `method="post"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding form attributes `action` and `method`

```
<form action="." method="post">...</form>

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ReserverSalle(request.POST)
    ....
else:
    form = ReserverSalle()
```

Comment: thank you very muck is worker  i forgeted the method

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify method and action in your form tag in html

```
<form method="POST" action="<<URL_TO_HANDLE_YOUR_FORM>>">
```

<> means Url specified in your URL.py which direct it to the views.py function you have written