# Cannot Retrieve Checkbox POST Data, form.is_valid() returns false

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am a beginner in Django/Python and whenever I try to submit my form the `is_valid()` method returns false. I have tried to display the errors using `form.errors` but it returns nothing or `{}`. When i try running the following code:

```
form.non_field_errors()
field_errors = [(field.label, field.errors) for field in form]
```

I get `[('', []), ('Required', [])]`

form.py

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
email = forms.EmailField(label='', max_length=100, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(
    attrs={'class': 'form-group form-control input-lg ', 'placeholder': 'Email'}), )
required = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Requirements.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

class Meta:
    model = Requirements
    fields = ['email', 'required']
```

views.py

```
def application_form(request):
try:
    form = ApplicationForm()
    context = {'form': form}

    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'requirements/job_specs.html', context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(form.is_valid(), form.errors)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return JsonResponse({'created': True})
    form.non_field_errors()
    field_errors = [(field.label, field.errors) for field in form]
    print(field_errors)
    return JsonResponse(form.errors.as_json(), safe=False)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

form = ApplicationForm(request.POST or None)
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, 'requirements/job_specs.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="application-form">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {{ form }}

                <div class="bg-light row" >
                    <div class="" id="btn-box">
                        <div class="col-md-12 d-grid gap-2 col-6 ">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>
```

I have tried to apply solutions from similar posts such as [Django forms is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760320/django-forms-is-not-valid) or [Django forms is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57760320/django-forms-is-not-valid) but none have helped to solve the problem. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of looking over the code, i finally found what was wrong with it. I simply had to add `request.POST or None` in `form = ApplicationForm()` and it worked like a charm.